# ServiceProvider not found error, when doing artisan commands

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add a new composer package but I'm getting the following error.

> Class 'Notflip\Menu\ToolServiceProvider' not found In ProviderRepository.php line 208

I had a ToolServiceProvider, but it has been renamed a long time ago.
So somewhere it must still be wrongly named, any idea as to how to find this?

#### Trace

```
Loading config file ./composer.json
Checked CA file /private/etc/ssl/cert.pem: valid
Executing command (/Users/miguel/Code/@modules/laravel-menu): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Reading /Users/miguel/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /Users/miguel/.composer/auth.json
Loading config file /Users/miguel/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /Users/miguel/.composer/auth.json
Reading /Users/miguel/.composer/auth.json
Reading /Users/miguel/Code/@modules/laravel-menu/vendor/composer/installed.json
Reading /Users/miguel/.composer/vendor/composer/installed.json
Running 1.8.4 (2019-02-11 10:52:10) with PHP 7.3.2 on Darwin / 18.2.0
Generating optimized autoload files> post-autoload-dump: Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> post-autoload-dump: @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Executing command (CWD): '/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.2/bin/php' -d allow_url_fopen='1' -d disable_functions='' -d memory_limit='1536M' artisan package:discover --ansi

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Notflip\Menu\ToolServiceProvider' not found
```

#### I've tried

- running composer dump-autoload (same error occurs)
- removing composer.lock
- doing a find in the whole project source, nothing named ToolServiceProvider is in there.

Comment: Try `grep -R ToolServiceProvider` from the root of your project if you're using Linux/Mac. There are grep tools that you can download for Windows.

Comment: Try running your commands with `-vvv` for debug level verbosity and see if you can find more information from the stack trace.

Comment: It just returns the same error message, not really where it's happening. I'll add the trace to my question

Comment: Have you searched in the `vendor` directory? Specifically in `vendor/composer/installed.json`? That is used by Laravel when doing package auto-discovery and from you stacktrace the exception seems to be thrown right after `package:discover` is triggered. There's also the brute force option of trying to delete the `vendor` directory and doing a fresh `composer install` to make sure any lingering references get removed.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to restart te webserver itself

Answer (score 1):

Delete file **bootstrap/cache/cache.php** and running composer dump-autoload